# Linebreak removed when building project (DevExpress + Resharper installed)

Tags: devexpress, resharper

**Software**

Visual Studio 2012-2013
ReSharper 7-8 (same with both in combination)

Nothing else is installed but general VS updates, DevExpress (not including CodeRush) and ReSharper.

Whenever I remove either plugin the problem is gone.

This issue seems to happen whenever I add a DevExpress grid control to a Form application. So Console applications are fine. The problem doesn't go away whenever I remove the grid control or when I remove the Form all together.

**Example**

The cursor is in the empty-line below.

```
private string Test()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello!");

    return "Hello!";
}
```

After building (or running as that builds as well):

```
private string Test()
{
        MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
        return "Hello!";
}
```

How would I solve this issue?
Let me know if you want more specific details.

PS:
I know that this question has been asked before. But this time around it's ReSharper + DevExpress that is causing this issue.

**Edit 2014-08-05:**

Not resolved yet. I just uninstalled CodeRush in the mean time.

Comment: I have the same problem? Any solution yet? I saw when you remove licensex.licx problem solved until file is created again.

Comment: @ymorales No, nothing yet. No clue on how to fix it without removing either plugin.

Comment: Have you checked Resharper > Options > Code Editing >  C# > Blank Lines > Keep max blank lines in code?

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič This did not solve the issue. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the （DevExpress） licenses.licx file in Properties will fix it.

Comment: After a time it appears again, very annoying

Answer (score 0):

I solved by disabling ReSharper (Itself). I think there is a conclusion with DevExpress and ReSharper Code Modification (or at least checking) mechanism. I've looked around tons of CodeRush and ReSharper options. Also scanned web many times. There is nothing! No one has met this problem but me :)